# Is there a faster alternative to python's Decimal?

Tags: python, python-decimal

Does anyone know of a faster decimal implementation in python?

As the example below demonstrates, the standard library's decimal module is ~100 times slower than `float`.

```py
from  timeit import Timer

def run(val, the_class):
    test = the_class(1)
    for c in xrange(10000):
        d = the_class(val)
        d + test
        d - test
        d * test
        d / test
        d ** test
        str(d)
        abs(d)    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = Timer("run(123.345, float)", "from decimal_benchmark import run")
    print "FLOAT", a.timeit(1)
    a = Timer("run('123.345', Decimal)", "from decimal_benchmark import run; from decimal import Decimal")
    print "DECIMAL", a.timeit(1)
```

*Outputs:*

```
FLOAT 0.040635041427
DECIMAL 3.39666790146
```

Comment: Do you have a specific performance goal -- i.e., an algorithm that's too slow?  Or, are you just hoping for hardware decimal like IBM builds in their mainframes?

Comment: Am I crazy or do the results become even more pronounced if you change the test value to some arbitrary float/decimal value?  Like so: test = the_class(115.45678)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [GMP](http://gmplib.org) library is one of the best arbitrary precision math libraries around, and there is a Python binding available at [GMPY](http://www.aleax.it/gmpy.html). I would try that method.

Comment: gmpy's mpf yields the same performance as float, it doesn't have inherent float issues such as precise compares and seems to be mostly compatible with Python Decimal interface.

Comment: cdecimal (mentioned below) has been good to me.  I don't know how accurate it is, but it does perform better than gmpy for these benchmarks - http://www.bytereef.org/mpdecimal/benchmarks.html

Comment: GMP doesn't do decimal math, though, so if you actually need decimal, this won't do the job. (GMP has rationals, similar to `fractions.Fraction`, but no decimal.)

Answer (score 26):

You can try [cdecimal](http://www.bytereef.org/mpdecimal/index.html):

```
from cdecimal import Decimal
```

As of Python 3.3, the cdecimal implementation is now the built-in implementation of the `decimal` standard library module, so you don't need to install anything. Just use `decimal`.

For Python 2.7, installing `cdecimal` and using it instead of `decimal` should provide a speedup similar to what Python 3 gets by default.

Comment: This is an especially good option for people who already have lots of code using the standard `decimal` module, because it is a drop-in replacement. In fact, it is included as the built-in `decimal` for Python 3.3 (released today!).

Comment: This change speed up my program by 33% in python 2.7! Not bad for a one character change! ;-)

Comment: `pip install m3-cdecimal`

Answer (score 3):

You should compare *Decimal* to *Long Integer* performance, not floating point. Floating point is mostly hardware these days. *Decimal* is used for **decimal precision**, while *Floating Point* is for wider range. Use the *decimal* package for monetary calculations.

To quote the *decimal* package manual:

> Decimal numbers can be represented exactly. In contrast, numbers like 1.1 do not have an exact representation in binary floating point. End users typically would not expect 1.1 to display as 1.1000000000000001 as it does with binary floating point.
>
> The exactness carries over into arithmetic. In decimal floating point, "0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 - 0.3" is exactly equal to zero. In binary floating point, result is 5.5511151231257827e-017. While near to zero, the differences prevent reliable equality testing and differences can accumulate. For this reason, decimal would be preferred in accounting applications which have strict equality invariants.

Comment: well, long is actually faster than float.

FLOAT 0.0551114582687
DECIMAL 3.39638546341
LONG 0.036625594419

Issue is with implementation of Python's Decimal.  It holds value as a list of ints.  Why not store the value as unbounded python long.  
Will try gmpy

Answer (score 3):

Use [cDecimal](http://www.bytereef.org/mpdecimal/index.html).

Adding the following to your benchmark:

```
a = Timer("run('123.345', Decimal)", "import sys; import cdecimal; sys.modules['decimal'] = cdecimal; from decimal_benchmark import run; from decimal import Decimal")
print "CDECIMAL", a.timeit(1)
```

My results are:

```
FLOAT 0.0257983528473
DECIMAL 2.45782495288
CDECIMAL 0.0687125069413
```

(Python 2.7.6/32, Win7/64, AMD Athlon II 2.1GHz)

Answer (score 0):

python Decimal is very slow, one can use float or a faster implementation of Decimal cDecimal.